# Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.6.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.6.0 and
>   Error:(42, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0  and    Error:(40, 13) Failed
>   to resolve: petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker:colorpicker-library:1.0.3

**gradle.build(module:lib)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'
//apply from: '../.publishing/sonatype.gradle'

archivesBaseName = 'android-crop'
ext {
    PUBLISH_GROUP_ID = 'com.vstechlab'
    PUBLISH_ARTIFACT_ID = 'easyfonts'
    PUBLISH_VERSION = '1.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22

        testApplicationId 'com.soundcloud.android.crop.test'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.7'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker:colorpicker-library:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'

}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blundell/release-android-library/master/android-release-aar.gradle'
```

**module example**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

archivesBaseName = 'android-crop-example'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
        versionName project.VERSION
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile project(':lib')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


}
```

**module NC**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/vsvankhede/maven/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    group = 'com.soundcloud.android'
    version = project.VERSION

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**setting gradle:**

```
include ':lib', ':example'
```

**error when i tried to run project**

```
i  tried and got these all   seee.......

    >Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':example'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':lib'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':lib:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker:colorpicker-library:1.0.3.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.pom
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.jar
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.pom
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.jar
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.pom
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.jar
        Required by:
            com.soundcloud.android:lib:1.0.1
      > Could not find com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.6.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/1.6.0/colorpicker-1.6.0.pom
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/1.6.0/colorpicker-1.6.0.jar
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/1.6.0/colorpicker-1.6.0.pom
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/1.6.0/colorpicker-1.6.0.jar
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/1.6.0/colorpicker-1.6.0.pom
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/rarepebble/colorpicker/1.6.0/colorpicker-1.6.0.jar
        Required by:
            com.soundcloud.android:lib:1.0.1
      > Could not find com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vstechlab/easyfonts/easyfonts/1.0.0/easyfonts-1.0.0.pom
            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vstechlab/easyfonts/easyfonts/1.0.0/easyfonts-1.0.0.jar
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/vstechlab/easyfonts/easyfonts/1.0.0/easyfonts-1.0.0.pom
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/vstechlab/easyfonts/easyfonts/1.0.0/easyfonts-1.0.0.jar
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/vstechlab/easyfonts/easyfonts/1.0.0/easyfonts-1.0.0.pom
            file:/C:/Users/Altaf/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/vstechlab/easyfonts/easyfonts/1.0.0/easyfonts-1.0.0.jar
        Required by:
            com.soundcloud.android:lib:1.0.1
```

Comment: At first `clean-rebuild-sync` remove extra `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'`

Comment: @eriuzo its working good ...

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya   did but nothing changed

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya    com.soundcloud.android:lib:1.0.1 
its libraby i m using for crop... but does this error means ?

Comment: you should call this .https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

Comment: ok.. but where should i call this ? and can u tell me the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.6.0
>        Error:(42, 13) Failed to resolve: com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0
>        Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker:colorpicker-library:1.0.3

It happens because these libraries **are not in MavenCentral**.

```
petrov.kristiyan.colorpicker:colorpicker-library:1.0.3.
com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0
com.rarepebble:colorpicker:1.6.0
```

Check for example this link:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/petrov/kristiyan/colorpicker/colorpicker-library/1.0.3/colorpicker-library-1.0.3.pom

This link **doesn't exist** and it should be the link of the pom file in the Maven Central using the library above.

May be you have to use a different maven repo.
I am not able to find it in MavenCentral or Jcenter repo.

If these libraries are on github you can try to use [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/docs/).

Add in the `root/build.gradle:`

```
allprojects {
        repositories { 
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
   }
```

Then in your project use:

```
  dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
   }
```

Comment: @altu Yes. As mentioned above this link doesn't exist. It is the reason of your issue. You are trying to add libraries that doesn't exist.

Comment: ok ...but i downloaded this colorpicker project from github its working good........  so can i grab maven from this proj and add it to my recent project?   any idea?

Comment: @altu With github try to use jitpack repo. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ...no...wait... The Big Thank........  the Smart ans ....saved lots of time .... but u answered when i poked u to ans me ..... bdw thnq .....i just got the libs functions ..... now time to implements lets see wat hapns........